# can't find my data write in hdfs with flume

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng

I am trying to write data in HDFS with Flume.
That's my flume agent configuration:

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 41414

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /etc/flume/conf/Data
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.callTimeout = 150000
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 600

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Evetything starts correctly and I start a telnet command to write on my port. After each entry I have this message from my window where I started the agent:

```
16/03/23 10:19:16 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating /etc/flume  /conf/FlumeData/FlumeData.1458728356159.tmp
16/03/23 10:29:17 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing /etc/flume/conf/FlumeData/FlumeData.1458728356159.tmp
16/03/23 10:29:17 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming /etc/flume/conf/FlumeData/FlumeData.1458728356159.tmp to /etc/flume/conf/FlumeData/FlumeData.145
```

Everything looks correct but, I have an issue, when I go trough my files system , I can't find the files which has been written, they just don't exist. Does anybody can help me? 
Thank you for taking time to read this, and sorry if my english is not perfect.

Comment: If you use Windows, How can you use path like `/etc/flume/conf/Data` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say "window" not windows. I am using hadoop on CentOs

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your hdfs file list ?

Comment: do you mean the path of my sink.hdfs or the hdfs repository in my hadoop cluster ?

Comment: No. the files in hdfs are listed in UI. That is the screenshot i wanted to see. Because I guess the hdfs directory is created under "/user/<your user name>"

Comment: Ah sure. It's weird but, I can see the files in the UI...

Answer (score 0):

Using complete HDFS URI will solve your problem.

Try this:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://namenode_hostname:port/etc/flume/conf/Data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to  write like this , try this code:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://namenode_hostname:port/etc/flume/conf/Data
```